# ISPManager ошибка настройки MX записи

Tags: ispmanager

Возникла необходимость настроить корпоративную почту для сайта. По ряду причин, основной из которых было то, что на другие сервисы электронной почты письма с нашего сервера не доходят (возможно, из-за того, что наш дырявый сервер засветился в спам-базах), в качестве сервиса был выбран mail.ru. 
В ходе настройки возникли проблемы: я в ISPManager внёс запись вида имя поддомена: @, тип записи: MX, данные: emx.mail.ru, приоритет: 10. Но при валидации mail.ru выдал ошибку - оказывается, адрес прописан не emx.mail.ru, а emx.mail.ru.site.com. Попытка перепроверить данные и повторно сохранить ничего не дала - в панели управления всё отображается правильно, а mail.ru выдаёт ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно настроить MX-запись в ISPManager.

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно поставить точку в конце записи 
`emx.mail.ru.`

Comment: Распишите ответ подробнее, добавьте может пруф-линков каких.